awk Script to Parse Logs and Extract Specific Values
I am trying to write a Bash script that processes log files and extracts specific values based on given conditions. The logs are located at a provided URL and contain real web server log data. Each line in the logs starts with a date and looks like this:
Apr 10 11:17:35 coderbyte app/web.3: IP_MASKED - - [10/Apr/2020:18:17:35 +0000] "GET
/backend/requests/editor/placeholder?shareLinkId=69dff0hba0nv HTTP/1.1" 200 148 "https://coderbyte.com"
"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0"

Apr 10 11:17:35 coderbyte heroku/router: at=info method=GET path="/backend/requests/editor/placeholder?
key=s2fwad25E" host=coderbyte.com request_id=b19a87a1-1bbb-46e7-b207-bd9f23d46afa fwd="108.31.000.000"
dyno=web.3 connect=0ms service=92ms status=200 bytes=3194 protocol=https

Apr 10 11:17:35 coderbyte heroku/router: at=info method=GET path="/backend/requests/editor/placeholder?
shareLinkId=tosrve4v8q8q" host=coderbyte.com request_id=910b07d1-3f71-4347-a1a7-bfa20384ef65
fwd="108.31.000.000" dyno=web.2 connect=1ms service=17ms status=200 bytes=4435 protocol=https

Apr 10 11:17:35 coderbyte heroku/router: at=info method=GET path="/backend/requests/editor/placeholder?
shareLinkId=tosrve4v8q8q" host=coderbyte.com request_id=097bf65e-e189-4f9f-9dfb-4758cff411b2
fwd="108.31.000.000" dyno=web.3 connect=1ms service=10ms status=200 bytes=4435 protocol=https

Apr 10 11:17:35 coderbyte app/web.2: IP_MASKED - - [10/Apr/2020:18:17:35 +0000] "GET
/backend/requests/editor/placeholder?key=s2fwad25E HTTP/1.1" 200 4263 "https://coderbyte.com"
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163
Safari/537.36"

Apr 10 11:17:35 coderbyte heroku/router: at=info method=GET path="/backend/requests/editor/placeholder?
shareLinkId=4eiramcayuo" host=coderbyte.com request_id=d48278c2-5731-464e-be38-ab9ad84ca4a8
fwd="108.31.000.000" dyno=web.4 connect=1ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=3194 protocol=https

Here is my current script:
awk '/coderbyte heroku\/router/ {
    match($0, /request_id=([^ ]+)/, req);
    match($0, /fwd="([^"]+)"/, fwd);
    req_value = req[1];
    fwd_value = fwd[1];

    if (fwd_value == "MASKED") {
        print req_value " [M]";
    } else {
        print req_value " [" fwd_value "]";
    }
}' web-logs-raw

But it keeps saying:
awk: line 2: syntax error at or near ,
awk: line 3: syntax error at or near ,

What am I doing wrong?

According to the GNU awk manual: "The array argument to match() is a gawk extension".  Are you using a non-GNU awk?

your script works for me (ie, no errors) when using GNU awk (aka gawk); if I switch to mawk the script generates the same error messages as you've posted;  as pjh has stated, it appears your version of awk does not support the 3rd arg to match()

I could not reproduce the output you posted.  Please post 'awk -W version' and 'od -x -a f1' for further analysis; thank you.

Sorry; please post 'od -x -a web-logs-raw' and 'od -x -a ' instead of 'od -x -a f1'

Is your INPUT really 6 multi-line (3 or 4 lines each) records separated by blank lines or did you just show it that way in the question because you couldn't figure out how to format it as 6 single-line records?

@markp-fuso when i tried running this locally on my system it didn't give any error also, but it was for an online test with an online editor for coderbtye, and it was throwing some errors that was why I'm surprised as it worked locally perfectly.

@Andrew this is the output of the awk version
random-funcs:     srandom/random
regex-funcs:      internal
compiled limits:
sprintf buffer    8192
maximum-integer   2147483647
mawk 1.3.4 20200120
Copyright 2008-2019,2020, Thomas E. Dickey
Copyright 1991-1996,2014, Michael D. Brennan

@Godwin I added the mawk tag so hopefully a mawk expert will chime in; also found an online mawk tool here:  https://www.ideone.com/465sVQ so I can play around with it and might be able to help. Also, BTW, here is the docs for mawk: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages//noble/man7/mawk-code.7.html and here is  summary of mawk vs awk vs gawk, etc.: https://www.baeldung.com/linux/awk-nawk-gawk-mawk-difference

I've reproduced the issue...

As others have mentioned, you aren't using GNU awk so match() doesn't have a 3rd argument, hence the syntax errors. Fortunately you don't need it for what you're trying to do.
If your input is actually 6 single lines like this:
$ cat web-logs-raw-1
Apr 10 11:17:35 coderbyte app/web.3: IP_MASKED - - [10/Apr/2020:18:17:35 +0000] "GET /backend/requests/editor/placeholder?shareLinkId=69dff0hba0nv HTTP/1.1" 200 148 "https://coderbyte.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0"
Apr 10 11:17:35 coderbyte heroku/router: at=info method=GET path="/backend/requests/editor/placeholder? key=s2fwad25E" host=coderbyte.com request_id=b19a87a1-1bbb-46e7-b207-bd9f23d46afa fwd="108.31.000.000" dyno=web.3 connect=0ms service=92ms status=200 bytes=3194 protocol=https
Apr 10 11:17:35 coderbyte heroku/router: at=info method=GET path="/backend/requests/editor/placeholder? shareLinkId=tosrve4v8q8q" host=coderbyte.com request_id=910b07d1-3f71-4347-a1a7-bfa20384ef65 fwd="108.31.000.000" dyno=web.2 connect=1ms service=17ms status=200 bytes=4435 protocol=https
Apr 10 11:17:35 coderbyte heroku/router: at=info method=GET path="/backend/requests/editor/placeholder? shareLinkId=tosrve4v8q8q" host=coderbyte.com request_id=097bf65e-e189-4f9f-9dfb-4758cff411b2 fwd="108.31.000.000" dyno=web.3 connect=1ms service=10ms status=200 bytes=4435 protocol=https
Apr 10 11:17:35 coderbyte app/web.2: IP_MASKED - - [10/Apr/2020:18:17:35 +0000] "GET /backend/requests/editor/placeholder?key=s2fwad25E HTTP/1.1" 200 4263 "https://coderbyte.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36"
Apr 10 11:17:35 coderbyte heroku/router: at=info method=GET path="/backend/requests/editor/placeholder? shareLinkId=4eiramcayuo" host=coderbyte.com request_id=d48278c2-5731-464e-be38-ab9ad84ca4a8 fwd="108.31.000.000" dyno=web.4 connect=1ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=3194 protocol=https

then you can do this with any POSIX awk:
$ awk '/coderbyte heroku\/router/ {
    match($0, /request_id=[^[:space:]]+/)
    req_value = substr($0, RSTART+11, RLENGTH-11)
    match($0, /fwd="[^"]+"/)
    fwd_value = substr($0, RSTART+5, RLENGTH-6)

    if (fwd_value == "MASKED") {
        print req_value " [M]";
    } else {
        print req_value " [" fwd_value "]";
    }
}' web-logs-raw-1
b19a87a1-1bbb-46e7-b207-bd9f23d46afa [108.31.000.000]
910b07d1-3f71-4347-a1a7-bfa20384ef65 [108.31.000.000]
097bf65e-e189-4f9f-9dfb-4758cff411b2 [108.31.000.000]
d48278c2-5731-464e-be38-ab9ad84ca4a8 [108.31.000.000]

or if the input truly is multi-line records separated by blank lines as shown in the question:
$ cat web-logs-raw-2
Apr 10 11:17:35 coderbyte app/web.3: IP_MASKED - - [10/Apr/2020:18:17:35 +0000] "GET
/backend/requests/editor/placeholder?shareLinkId=69dff0hba0nv HTTP/1.1" 200 148 "https://coderbyte.com"
"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0"

Apr 10 11:17:35 coderbyte heroku/router: at=info method=GET path="/backend/requests/editor/placeholder?
key=s2fwad25E" host=coderbyte.com request_id=b19a87a1-1bbb-46e7-b207-bd9f23d46afa fwd="108.31.000.000"
dyno=web.3 connect=0ms service=92ms status=200 bytes=3194 protocol=https

Apr 10 11:17:35 coderbyte heroku/router: at=info method=GET path="/backend/requests/editor/placeholder?
shareLinkId=tosrve4v8q8q" host=coderbyte.com request_id=910b07d1-3f71-4347-a1a7-bfa20384ef65
fwd="108.31.000.000" dyno=web.2 connect=1ms service=17ms status=200 bytes=4435 protocol=https

Apr 10 11:17:35 coderbyte heroku/router: at=info method=GET path="/backend/requests/editor/placeholder?
shareLinkId=tosrve4v8q8q" host=coderbyte.com request_id=097bf65e-e189-4f9f-9dfb-4758cff411b2
fwd="108.31.000.000" dyno=web.3 connect=1ms service=10ms status=200 bytes=4435 protocol=https

Apr 10 11:17:35 coderbyte app/web.2: IP_MASKED - - [10/Apr/2020:18:17:35 +0000] "GET
/backend/requests/editor/placeholder?key=s2fwad25E HTTP/1.1" 200 4263 "https://coderbyte.com"
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163
Safari/537.36"

Apr 10 11:17:35 coderbyte heroku/router: at=info method=GET path="/backend/requests/editor/placeholder?
shareLinkId=4eiramcayuo" host=coderbyte.com request_id=d48278c2-5731-464e-be38-ab9ad84ca4a8
fwd="108.31.000.000" dyno=web.4 connect=1ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=3194 protocol=https

then just set RS to null to use paragraph mode, again using any awk:
$ awk -v RS= '/coderbyte heroku\/router/ {
    match($0, /request_id=[^[:space:]]+/)
    req_value = substr($0, RSTART+11, RLENGTH-11)
    match($0, /fwd="[^"]+"/)
    fwd_value = substr($0, RSTART+5, RLENGTH-6)

    if (fwd_value == "MASKED") {
        print req_value " [M]";
    } else {
        print req_value " [" fwd_value "]";
    }
}' web-logs-raw-2
b19a87a1-1bbb-46e7-b207-bd9f23d46afa [108.31.000.000]
910b07d1-3f71-4347-a1a7-bfa20384ef65 [108.31.000.000]
097bf65e-e189-4f9f-9dfb-4758cff411b2 [108.31.000.000]
d48278c2-5731-464e-be38-ab9ad84ca4a8 [108.31.000.000]


nice work, Edxxxxxx

Let web-logs-raw content be
Apr 10 11:17:35 coderbyte app/web.3: IP_MASKED - - [10/Apr/2020:18:17:35 +0000] "GET
/backend/requests/editor/placeholder?shareLinkId=69dff0hba0nv HTTP/1.1" 200 148 "https://coderbyte.com"
"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0"

Apr 10 11:17:35 coderbyte heroku/router: at=info method=GET path="/backend/requests/editor/placeholder?
key=s2fwad25E" host=coderbyte.com request_id=b19a87a1-1bbb-46e7-b207-bd9f23d46afa fwd="108.31.000.000"
dyno=web.3 connect=0ms service=92ms status=200 bytes=3194 protocol=https

Apr 10 11:17:35 coderbyte heroku/router: at=info method=GET path="/backend/requests/editor/placeholder?
shareLinkId=tosrve4v8q8q" host=coderbyte.com request_id=910b07d1-3f71-4347-a1a7-bfa20384ef65
fwd="108.31.000.000" dyno=web.2 connect=1ms service=17ms status=200 bytes=4435 protocol=https

Apr 10 11:17:35 coderbyte heroku/router: at=info method=GET path="/backend/requests/editor/placeholder?
shareLinkId=tosrve4v8q8q" host=coderbyte.com request_id=097bf65e-e189-4f9f-9dfb-4758cff411b2
fwd="108.31.000.000" dyno=web.3 connect=1ms service=10ms status=200 bytes=4435 protocol=https

Apr 10 11:17:35 coderbyte app/web.2: IP_MASKED - - [10/Apr/2020:18:17:35 +0000] "GET
/backend/requests/editor/placeholder?key=s2fwad25E HTTP/1.1" 200 4263 "https://coderbyte.com"
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163
Safari/537.36"

Apr 10 11:17:35 coderbyte heroku/router: at=info method=GET path="/backend/requests/editor/placeholder?
shareLinkId=4eiramcayuo" host=coderbyte.com request_id=d48278c2-5731-464e-be38-ab9ad84ca4a8
fwd="108.31.000.000" dyno=web.4 connect=1ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=3194 protocol=https

then
awk '/coderbyte heroku\/router/ {
    match($0, /request_id=([^ ]+)/, req);
    match($0, /fwd="([^"]+)"/, fwd);
    req_value = req[1];
    fwd_value = fwd[1];

    if (fwd_value == "MASKED") {
        print req_value " [M]";
    } else {
        print req_value " [" fwd_value "]";
    }
}' web-logs-raw

gives output
 []
 []
 []
 []

when using GNU Awk 5.3.1, so you are apparently not using GNU AWK, check if you have one, if yes (or you are allowed to install gawk) you should change awk to gawk to resolve syntax error. Observe that there is another problem, request= and fwd= are not at same line as line with heroku. This is easy to counteract in GNU AWK, as it is enough to engage paragraph mode, by setting RS to empty string namely
gawk 'BEGIN{RS=""}/coderbyte heroku\/router/ {
    match($0, /request_id=([^ ]+)/, req);
    match($0, /fwd="([^"]+)"/, fwd);
    req_value = req[1];
    fwd_value = fwd[1];

    if (fwd_value == "MASKED") {
        print req_value " [M]";
    } else {
        print req_value " [" fwd_value "]";
    }
}' web-logs-raw

will give output
b19a87a1-1bbb-46e7-b207-bd9f23d46afa [108.31.000.000]
910b07d1-3f71-4347-a1a7-bfa20384ef65
fwd="108.31.000.000" [108.31.000.000]
097bf65e-e189-4f9f-9dfb-4758cff411b2
fwd="108.31.000.000" [108.31.000.000]
d48278c2-5731-464e-be38-ab9ad84ca4a8
fwd="108.31.000.000" [108.31.000.000]

Explanation: when RS is set to empty string GNU AWK assumes records are separated by blank lines.

that's not the error OP got
